# How to delay a python program in progress through another python code (in Raspberry Pi)

Tags: python, process, raspberry-pi

I want to know how to delay and execute a python program in progress in Raspberry Pi through another python code. For example, I have a python file named example.py which contains GPIO commands and the python file is in progress. But I want the GPIO process to be delayed or stop, so I want a python file named delay.py which will delay the example.py process and execute.py which will execute the example.py process. What should the code in delay.py and execute.py be? What kind of python code should I write to delay or execute ongoing python process in Raspberry Pi?

Comment: perhaps you could have both programs reading and writing to a file that indicates when one should run, and the other should pause

Answer (score 0):

Every python script run on python.exe process. Just find the process name(it's better to find PID)  that you want to pause or stop and by using system library you can stop that. But here is a link which solve your problem in Pi:

[Can't kill a python script](http://Every%20python%20script%20run%20on%20python.exe%20process.%20Just%20find%20the%20process%20name(it's%20better%20to%20find%20PID)%20%20that%20you%20want%20to%20pause%20or%20stop%20and%20by%20using%20system%20library%20you%20can%20stop%20that)